# How to know which web server is running on my application

Tags: python, apache, nginx, webserver

I have my web application built in python. I wish to have ssl certificate installed. How would I know which web server is running on my server? nginx or apache? Currently if i stop **apache** or **nginx**, the server does not shut down. I am able to see the running application even when the web server is down.

Answer (score 2):

Use netstat in this case.

This will allow you to see what exactly is listening on the TCP port.

If you happen to be using Windows:

```
netstat -a -n -b
```

Linux:

```
sudo netstat -ltnp
```